# lxml not found, please install it in @Colaboratory

Tags: python, lxml, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to port my code on google Colaboratory.
It's weird that even I did

```
!pip3 install xml
```

in my code.
It still require me to install lxml.

Does anybody have the problem??

```
****Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages****
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-eda66c9ec97a> in <module>()
     48 #df = financial_statement(2017,3)
...
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parser_dispatch(flavor)
    695     else:
    696         if not _HAS_LXML:
--> 697             raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
    698     return _valid_parsers[flavor]
    699 

**ImportError: lxml not found, please install it**


**code:**

!pip3 install lxml

import requests

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import keras

import lxml

import html5lib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f_states=   pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

Answer (score 9):

After install use pip or apt, you need to restarting the runtime using “Runtime / Restart runtime…”

Comment: In particular, you need this whenever you want to reload a module that you've already imported.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your solution.
After restart, it can work. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying on google colab. i  have tried every thing for 2 hours finally this worked for me.

```
url = 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states'
pd.read_html(url, flavor='html5lib`)
```

Official document suggests:

> The default of None tries to use lxml to parse and if that fails it falls back on bs4 + html5lib.
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html